# How to show choice field in template form

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, categories, choicefield

I want to show the Django choice field from Model on the HTML template like in the following picture. I can't see anything after doing this code.

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    TITLE_CHOICES = [
        ('MR', 'Mr.'),
        ('MRS', 'Mrs.'),
        ('MS', 'Ms.'),
    ]
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)
```

**views.py**

```
def AuthorView(request):
    form = Author(request.POST or None)
    title = Author.objects.all()

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "ttile": title,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return render(request, 'index.html')

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
   <select name="confirm_type" id="confirm_type">
        {% for object in ttile %}

            <option value="by_email"> {{ object }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
   </select>
```

[image: I want to show like this picture.]